# CreateJs Drawing with alpha

Tags: createjs

I implemented a little drawing function into my app with CreateJS like so:

```
var currentPosition = this.posOnStage(event);

    var drawing = container.getChildByName('drawing');
    drawing.graphics.ss(this.brushSize, "round").s(this.brushColor);
    drawing.graphics.mt(this._lastMousePosition.x, this._lastMousePosition.y);
    drawing.graphics.lt(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y);
    drawing.alpha = this.brushAlpha;
    container.updateCache(this.enableErasing ? "destination-out" : "source-over");
    drawing.graphics.clear();

    this._lastMousePosition = this.posOnStage(event);
```

As you can see, the alpha value of this drawing can change. Sadly you can draw over a point you once did draw, so when you draw over a point multiple times the alpha effect will go away. Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks :)

EDIT:
[image]

I tried it like gskinner and  Lanny 7 proposed, but it didn't work. I attached a image so you can see the problem.

Comment: You are drawing everything at 100% and just changing the overall opacity. If you change the opacity of the color instead, then it will have an iterative effect. What are you using for brush color? If you use an rgba value "rgba(255,125,25,0.5)" it should give you the effect you want.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Lanny, apply the alpha to the actual stroke, not to the Shape. You can use Graphics methods to help with this.

For example:

`// set the brush color to red with the current brush alpha:
this.brushColor = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255, 0, 0, this.brushAlpha);`